# How to find unit normal vector of a 2d line

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been given the line equation of $y-8=0$, and have to find the unit normal vector? How would I go about doing this? is there a specific equation I need to use?

Following this I have been given the question: Find the equation of a line passing through point $A(9, −6)$ and orthogonal to vector $v=[−4,0]^T$. Which i am also unsure how to complete.

Any help would be much appreciated, it's been quite a while since i have done this sort of maths.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If the line is put in the form
$$
ax+by=c\tag{1}
$$
that is equivalent to
$$
(a,b)\cdot(x,y)=c\tag{2}
$$
which says that the points on the line are perpendicular to the vector $(a,b)$. Thus, the unit normals would be
$$
\pm\frac{(a,b)}{|(a,b)|}\tag{3}
$$
In the case of $y-8=0$, you get $0x+1y=8$, so the unit normals would be
$$
\pm\frac{(0,1)}{|(0,1)|}=\pm(0,1)\tag{4}
$$

---

Reversing the process in $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get that
$$
-4x+0y=C\tag{5}
$$
is perpendicular to $\begin{bmatrix}-4&0\end{bmatrix}^T$. Plug $\begin{bmatrix}9&-6\end{bmatrix}^T$ into $(5)$ to get $C=-36$
$$
\begin{align}
-4x+0y&=-36\\
x&=9\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
which would be the line orthogonal to $\begin{bmatrix}-4&0\end{bmatrix}^T$ and passing through $\begin{bmatrix}9&-6\end{bmatrix}^T$.

Comment: Is the relation b/w (a,b) and (x,y) just a clever observation here, or is it part of some (line) rule(s)? Can you point to more info, thanks.

Comment: @user362515: $(1)$ and $(2)$ are just rewriting things. The fact that the points $(x,y)$ that satisfy $(2)$ lie in a line that is perpendicular to $(a,b)$ is a useful fact. This is actually extendible to higher dimensions. Suppose that $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ lie in a subspace that is perpendicular to (a,b). Then, $(a,b)\cdot(x_1-x_0,y_1-y_0)=0$. That is, $(a,b)\cdot(x_1,y_1)=(a,b)\cdot(x_0,y_0)=c$.

Answer (score 4):

For the general case, to get a vector perpendicular to a given one, you want the dot product to be zero.  That means a vector perpendicular to $[a,b]$ is $[-b,a]$.  Then you have to scale it to make it a unit vector.

In your specific cases, there are zeros involved.  Have you plotted $y-8=0$?  You should be able to find a perpendicular vector by inspection.

For the second one, what is the direction of $v$?  What directions are perpendicular to it?

Comment: we arent given a direction of the vector, but i'd guess it would be perpendicular to the line i have to find, but im not sure how to find it as i have only been given one point it passes through. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @JoePerkins:   The vector is $[-4,0]^T$  Presumably the root is the origin.  Does that help?

Comment: so it would simply follow the x axis left 4 units? making the line that im trying to find y=0?

Comment: @JoePerkins:  To the first question, yes.  But then you need a vertical line, while $y=0$ is horizontal, and you need it to go through $(9,-6)$

Comment: Ok I think i understand, My line is going to be from points (0,4), to (9,-6)? and from there i just need to find the equation which im pretty sure i can do.

Comment: The vectors orthogonal to $v$ are horizontal (and you lost a minus sign on $v$) but go through $(9,-6)$, so the line is $y=-6$.  for the first, you line is $y=8$, which is horizontal, so the normal is vertical.  A vertical unit vector is $(0,1)$ or $(0,-1)$